# Backup of Ethereum Node

Tags: go-ethereum, backup, chaindata

I want to know how to take a backup of Private Ethereum Blockchain (chain data folder) while the chain is running.

The problem is that suppose my chain height is at 1000 and it gets crashed or if I kill the process manually and after that I start the chain again then it never starts the chain from the height where it has stooped.

But if I close the chain properly then it gets started from where it has stooped.
After closing the chain properly I get the message as

> ```
> Blockchain manager stopped.  
> Stopping ethereum protocol  
> Ethereum Protocol Stopped  
> Transaction pool stopped.  
> Database Closed
> ```

I think the reason is it is keeping the blocks in RAM for some time and after some height it is storing it in the database.

I tried to take a backup from geth console :

```
admin.exportChain()
```

and it worked well, but the problem is as we can't use admin from **web3** module so it is not possible from application.

I even tried **import** and **export** option of **geth**, but to do that the chain should not be running.

so is there any way to take a backup of chaindata folder.

Answer (score 1):

I *never* backup my geth nodes that way. I personally would do daily incremental rsync backups, followed by weekly full backups of your `chaindata` folder, and all other folders containing transaction data, keystore, etc..

Comment: Hey @hextet. Can the files backed up by rsync backups be used to setup a new node if the current node some how malfunctions?

Comment: And would this work while the node is running, as the OP asked? What is your `rsync` command?