# Can you backup an ethereum node while running?

Tags: go-ethereum, backup

The question is pretty straightforward. I want to routinely backup the data folders of a an ethereum (`geth`) node, so that in the event of a disk failure I can recover quickly without having to resynchronize from scratch.

Can I do it while the node is running, and if yes how?

As a matter of fact the same question goes for other networks (e.g. arbitrum)

The question might seem similar to [Backup of Ethereum Node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48828/backup-of-ethereum-node), but it is not really since the actual question of whether you can do backups while a node is running is not answered.